# Avoiding deserialization cost when reading Parquet files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, avro, parquet

We are using Parquet, Avro and Spark for analytics.

About 40-50% of our query time is spent in deserializing data. That's the Parquet-Avro interaction (AvroRecordMaterializer) in constructing Avro's GenericRecords. We have determined this by using a custom ReadSupport class with a dummy record materializer (which does nothing with the data passed to it).

What options do we on optimizing this area? We could move away from Avro, but with protobufs we observed comparable overhead. What do others do to overcome deserialization overhead?

Additionally, it seems that even with a predicate push down (Filter2 API) not matching some rows, we are still seeing the overhead for cases where row groups are not excluded based on metadata checks. How can we avoid the whole record deserialization when the Parquet predicate doesn't match?

Thanks!